# How to define a regular expression to extract currency symbol from price string?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a price string from which I want to get the currency symbol (symbol has variable length).

The price can be presented in different formats. I am removing the points, commas and digits but sometimes a comma or point is shown before the currency symbol

```
var k = "111,112,258$".replace(/\d+([,.]\d+)?/g, "");
console.log(k) //log shows ,$
```

I think the second comma or point is the problem. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This replaces digits, commas, dots, and spaces from your input string

```
var k = "111,112.111$".replace(/[\d,.\s]/g, "");
console.log(k) // $
```

EDIT:

If you want to support Arabic/Indian numbers, you could extend it further like

```
var k = "١٢٣,١١$".replace(/[\d,.\s,١-٩]/g, "");
console.log(k) // $
```

Comment: thank you ! it's working. but can you explain what was wrong with my regular expression?

Comment: @mike The problem with the RegEx you posted is that 
1st match will capture `111,112` because (`,112`) matches the 1st capturing group `([,.]\d+)?` 
2nd match (because it’s global ‘g’ flag) will try to look for a digit first, that’s why it starts matching from `258` leaving the last comma unmatched

Comment: @mike to make it work with your posted RegEx, just replace the question `?` with `*`, that means it will match ZERO or more of that part `(,\d+)`

Comment: @mike no worries

Comment: Why do you support whitespaces? a price should not include whitespace, no?

Comment: @alfasin In Germany for instance they put € at the end with space before, unlike in Ireland, they put it at the beginning without spaces. So IMO it's a valid assumption to consider

Answer (score 2):

You can simplify the regex and replace only the characters you're interested in without mentioning the others:

```
"111,112,258$".replace(/[\d,.]/g, "")
```

output (screenshot done from node terminal):

[image]

Comment: i don't want the numbers either

Comment: i tried "111,112,258$".replace(/\d+([,\.]\d+)?/g, ""); but it didn't work

Comment: @mike oh sorry I missed that, in that case it's simple - just add `\d` to the regex, see corrected answer above.

Comment: @alfasin dot inside brackets does not need to be escaped

Comment: so what's the issue with my regular expression then?

Comment: @mike a fix to the regex introduced in the question will be: `"111,112,258$".replace(/\d+([,.]\d+)+/g, "")` pay attention that the only change is: the last `?` is replaced with `+` because after the first series of digits there's a repeated pattern of "comma + digits" and the original regex covers only multiple digits but not multiple commas from that point till the end.